# BigQuery API does not return newest table of a dataset

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

I need to find the most recent table by creation time in a BigQuery dataset. I have an Google Apps Script function that could find the newest table and it used to work fine when there were only a few tables in the dataset, but ever since there are more tables in the dataset(72 to be exact) it just keeps returning the same "newest" table (e.g tablename_1623468444656), even though I know that there exists a newer one.

The problem seems to be the size of the logger output, because when I log the output it says: "Logging output too large. Truncating output". But regardless of whether I log the output or not, it just returns the allegedly newest table (e.g tablename_1623468444656).

I don't know what I need to change so that the function can find the actual newest table again. The function looks like this:

```
function findNewestTables() {
    const data = BigQuery.Tables.list('Projectname', 'Datasetname');
    let
      maxSoFar = 0,
      id = ""; 

    data.tables.forEach(table => {
      const time = parseInt(table.creationTime);
      if(time > maxSoFar){
        maxSoFar = time; 
        id = table.id;
      }
    });
    const formattedId = id.replace(":", ".");
    // return formattedId;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(formattedId);
};
```

Part of the output looks something like this and then it is just abruptly cut off.

```
Logging output too large. Truncating output. { totalItems: 72,
  kind: 'bigquery#tableList',
  etag: '7+eK1beNA7CVq0xasdfdsfYw==',
  nextPageToken: 'Team_1627356444573',
  tables: 
   [ { id: 'tablename_1623468444656',
       type: 'TABLE',
       kind: 'bigquery#table',
       creationTime: '1628585864499',
       tableReference: [Object] },
     { tableReference: [Object],
       id: 'tablename_1623554844685',
       kind: 'bigquery#table',
       creationTime: '1628585864503',
       type: 'TABLE' },
     { id: 'tablename_1623641244614',
       type: 'TABLE',
       kind: 'bigquery#table',
       tableReference: [Object],
       creationTime: '1628585864573' },
     { tableReference: [Object],
       kind: 'bigquery#table',
       creationTime: '1628585864714',
       type: 'TABLE',
       id: 'tablename_1623727644545' },
     { tableReference: [Object],
       kind: 'bigquery#table',
       type: 'TABLE',
       creationTime: '1628585865059',
       id: 'tablename_1623814044558' },
     { creationTime: '1628585865037',
       id: 'tablename_1623900444676',
       type:
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

So, this is one of those cases where you need to paginate.  See the `nextPageToken`?  If that value isn't empty/nil, it means you can call tables.list again and pass that token as the `pageToken` GET param in a subsequent request to get the next page of results.

More details about the API: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/list